# What is an intuitive synonym for an "implementation" of an idea?

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to build a website/community around 3 types of content;

1. Problems (*I get sunburnt and really hot in summer*)
2. Ideas (*A hat with a built-in fan that protects you from the sun and keeps you cool at the same time*)
3. **Implementation** (*Here's a link to an online store that sells solar-powered hats with fans*)

The notion that Problems can spawn ideas to solve them is intuitive to me (and hopefully to the user), but I'm struggling to find a better word for the *implementation* (ie. the tangible thing that makes the idea happen).

Note that this concept doesn't have to be a product as in the example above, it could be *Here's a schematic I came up with for building a hat with a fan built into it*.

For context, this is for [a public-facing website](https://www.portnovel.com) designed to foster innovation and collaboration, so understanding by a wide range of speakers is essential. I think the word "Implementation" is not intuitive, as it won't be clear to the user that an implementation follows from an idea.

Some synonyms I've considered myself are;

- Product - the implementation may not be something that is actually sold or marketed, it could be something as simple as *life-hacks*.
- Solution - I'm concerned this might imply that "Solutions" are the thing that follows from "Problems", whereas that's already used by the concept of an "Idea"
- Outcome - too vague and doesn't intuitively follow as the implementation of an "idea".

What's a better synonym for "Implementation" here?

Comment: I like _realisation_ which was mentioned on that linked answer as well.

Comment: No; it's a duplicate. SWR, not just 'noun', tag.  'Fruition' was upvoted. // SWR's should have an example sentence with a space where the word will be slotted in. 'Synonyms' really should too, as they're usually requests for single words (though here, your frame is clear enough). But the answers are essentially duplicates of what you might get here ('concretization' is rarefied and sounds totally off-register).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks

Answer (score 1):

*Ideas* are abstract things as such and need to be *concretized.*

I suggest, therefore, **concretization.**

Here's how AHD defines **concretize**—

**Concretize**

> To make real or specific:

*“Vignettes ... that concretize his thoughts and emotions” (Michael H. Begnel).*